# can someone explain a good example which show when the 'yield' instruction could be used and why i can't use return as well?(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, generator, yield

*I can't understand how the generator-function with 'yield' can help me. I can just 'return' a list when I need. For example function:*

```
   def sqr(x):
       for a in range(1, x+1):
           yield a**2
```

I can do for example something like that:
`sq_gen = sqr(20)`
and there is a generator object. There is also 'next' method which returns every new element of that object but WHY and for what reason?

Comment: So it' s about the memory and this kind of functions don't fill the stack?

Comment: To give an example for why it's needed, `range()`, is a generator. If it wouldn't be and you wanted to iterate from `0` to `10000000000`, it would create a `list` of `10000000000` elements and that entire `list` would be in memory. Since it's a generator it `yield`s an element, preserve its state, and when you need another, it `yield`s another. The important thing here is that only one element is in memory at a time.

Comment: This is also helpful in many other instances. Like iterating through the lines of a file without having to have its entire contents in memory.